# Google play Console: Property incorrect_psl_declaration.TITLE not found

Tags: google-play-console

I just pushed my new updates on play store and all over sudden am getting this error, I have tried to research online for answers but I get non, any help what this error means and how to fix it?
[image]

Any help and guidance on how to fix this is highly appreciated

Comment: I had the same problem today.

Comment: How did you resolve?

Comment: I just got this as well.  What third party libraries do you have as part of your app?  I have AppsFyler (marketing/ads), and Bugsnag (bug reports/crashes).  I'm thinking perhaps I didn't know that I was using an advertising id or something similar as a device identifier.

Answer (score 6):

I'm glad to see others have been impacted and it was not just me!

It seems to be a bug with the Google review system. Best thing to do is contact them via the link to their form in the footer of the email you received.

*Update 2:*

I did not take any action and passed the review process today.

*Update 1:*

I received the reply I have screenshot below, which does not help much. I asked what the notification was about and he did not address the issue at all, so now I don't know what to do. However he did confirm that my app was currently in the review queue, so maybe we just need to wait. Maybe the email notification with errors can be ignored. I will wait a few days to see if my app passes review without taking any further action.

[image: Reply from Google]

Comment: Could you please inform us when they reply?

Comment: On what action should be taken, because I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @benazirSh I will update my answer when they have replied

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here

Comment: @Phil bro see my answer in this question, I've posted it

Answer (score 2):

I've just updated my Data Safety forms adding `Device or other identifiers` because my app request Ad Id, BSSID etc.

[image: Data Safety]

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, and the solution is :

You need to check if you're using third-party libraries (in my case, ***IronSource*** and ***AdMob***) that collect the user data.

If you're using IronSource you need to fill the Data Safety from here :

https://developers.is.com/ironsource-mobile/general/google-data-safety-questionnaire/

After you fill the Data Safety, hit the save button and wait for the review to complete.